# Android plugin - Cannot reference AAR's resources

Tags: android, kotlin, aar

**EDIT:**

After further exploring the question actually is: How to include a AAR file in a plugin for an app?

I am writing a plugin, then the plugin is loaded by another app. In this case I cannot find the resources. But I can access all classes. 
If I turn my plugin into a standalone app. I can access even resources.

How to make the aar work if included in the plugin and loaded in another app?

---

So I know there is a million questions like this, however nothing seems to work, so maybe I am missing something.

1. I created a simple android library - File -> New -> New module -> Android library
2. I added the library into my project

   ```
   flatDir{ dirs "./aar" } // project gradle
   implementation (name: "the_library_name", ext: "aar") // module gradle
   ```
3. I can access any Kotlin class from the library
4. I cannot access any resource neither from aar itself or the project referencing the aar

In my project: **Resouces$NotFoundException: String resource ID...**

```
context.getString(R.string.some_string)
// R -> com.my_project.test.R
```

In my library code: **Resouces$NotFoundException: Resource ID  type #0x5 is not valid**

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout,....)
// R -> com.my_library.name.R
```

In both cases the code fails when trying to reference AAR's resource. But this works:

```
com.my_library.name.LibraryClass()
```

Did a generate the AAR wrong? Is there a special step to take to allow the access to resources? Am I including it wrong in my app?

NOTE: The library is written in kotlin, the app is a combination of kotlin and Java. I am accessing the resources from kotlin classes. Not sure if that matters or not.

NOTE2: I first started my library in the app project - meaning I could see the libraries code in a module and change the code. That wasn't working either. Same problem with resources.

NOTE3: The application does not have any default activity. It is a plugin for another app. I think that has something to do with the fact it is not working. I tried some "sample" projects, and it is working fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question as it seems it is not related to AAR. It looks like the third party apps fault, because this approach seems to be working anywhere else.